# Crossdomain image doesn't appears on ios7

Tags: html, css, image, cross-domain, ios7

I have following code on the page http://m.parkgrandlondon.co.uk/delete/sample_image.html
This is a mobile version of a website.

```
<h1>Image 1 from remote domain </h1>
<img  src="http://www.parkgrandlondon.co.uk/images1/big/bg1259835515pg-dbl.jpg" />

<br />
<br />

<h1>Image 2 from same domain</h1>
<img  src="bg1259835515pg-dbl.jpg" />
```

The 1st image come from the main website the second image for testing purpose is put on the same domain.
The 1st image doesn't appears on iOS7. It works fine on other browsers and OS

Anybody has any solution?

Comment: I would take a look to the server logs and see what happens in the first case. It may be a wrong redirection based on some script that is filtering requests by OS ?

Comment: Have check if the second image is correctly loaded?
Also, try to set up a width and height

Comment: Can anyone give me a link to a webpage that calls image from a different domain and works on iOS 7 ?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan you are right. When I removed .htaccess temporarily from main website it worked. Thanks